# RAM size increase with mysqld.exe and my application

Tags: java, mysql, performance, deployment

```
In my Task Manager i found that Mysqld.exe takes till 130kb of RAM size and once it reaches this size my application size(javaw.exe) in RAM is gradually increasing which causes the system to hang.  Why this takes place? Anyone Please Help. My application is written in java. becaus of this my application is running very slowly
```

This is how i made the connection. this thread will be called for every second

```
thread_sample_s1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ResultSet ress1 = null;
                Statement state_men = null;
                Connection conn_sample_s1 = null;
               try {
                    conn_sample_s1= (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(url_s1+db_s1,user_s1,pwd_s1);
                } catch (SQLException e3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block    e3.printStackTrace();
                } 
             conn_sample_s1.setAutoCommit(false);
             state_men = conn_sample_s1.createStatement();
             //--->> Queries 
             state_men.close(); 
            ress1.close(); 
            conn_sample_s1.commit(); 
            conn_sample_s1.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} }); thread_sample_s1.start();
```

there are more than 100 threads similar to this. which will be started newly for each second

Comment: Unless you post some sample code showing how you use your DB connections, no one can do more than guess randomly, which is a waste of time.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  Have you changed any of the default values in my.cnf?  What is the limit on Java's memory?

Comment: 2Gb RAM and 512mb limit for jvm

Comment: i have posted the connection sample above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My application is written in java. becaus of this my application is running very slowly

I'm afraid, it's more you than Java. Running hundreds of SQL queries per seconds in Java is definitely no big deal.

One important thing you're missing is [a connection pool](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP). Another one is [prepared statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). And trust me, there's much more to learn.

It's also quite possible, that the DB is the bottleneck. Your queries may be the problem and then optimizing the Java part won't help. Measure and then update your question.

Comment: I have added performance_schema=0 in my.ini of mysql. This solves my problem. Also i have implemented connection pool

Comment: @user_1992 Nice! Note that prepared statements are essential for security, too (google SQL injection).